# FBLoginView - loginViewFetchedUserInfo call more than once by FacebookSDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk, loginview

I have a problem with delegate function loginViewFetchedUserInfo in FBLoginView. I put a log inside function and sometimes the NSLog print multiple times than once. Why does would that be happen.

Does anyone know the reason?